# Is $2^{2n} = O(2^n)$?

Tags: computational-complexity

Is $2^{2n} = O(2^n)$?

My solution is:

$2^n 2^n \leq C_{1}2^n$

$2^n \leq C_{1}$,

**TRUE**.

Is this correct?

Comment: You're saying **all** powers of two are bounded by a constant?

Comment: Please, explain me, I don't understand what is what I must to prove, Thanks.

Comment: Is there really a constant $C_1$ such that $2^n \le C_1$ for **all** $n$?

Comment: You have to figure out whether or not there exists a constant $C$ such that $2^{2n}\le C2^n$ (or equivalently as you note, $2^n\le C$) for all $n$ beyond a certain, say, $n_0$. In other words, here you have to decide whether or not the integer powers of two have an upper bound.

Comment: @Albert: En inglés, no existe el signo de interrogación izquierdo.

Comment: On the other hand; the ¿ is unlikely to confuse anyone.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry by my English please.

Comment: @Mark: True... but there are some LaTeX artifacts that produce them, so best to not include them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $2^{2n}=O(2^n)$, then there is a constant $C$ and an integer $M$ such that *for  all* $n\ge M$, the inequality $2^{2n}\le C 2^n$ holds.

This would imply that  $2^n\cdot 2^n\le C 2^n$ for all $n\ge M$, which in  turn implies $$\tag{1} 2^n\le C  \quad  {\bf for\ all } \quad n\ge M. $$ Can such $C$ and $M$ exist? Note the right hand side of $(1)$ is fixed, and the left hand side...

Comment: Ok, now I understand, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

$x^n=o(y^n)$ iff $x<y$, as $(\frac{x}{y})^n\rightarrow 0$. Here 4 and 2, so no.